# AngularJS not updating template variable when scope changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

This will be one of those stupid questions that is very obvious to the experts.

I have a websocket pushing data to a service where I'm trying to store the data and have it pushed to a template via my controller.

The data is coming in and updating the variable but the UI only updates is I perform a action on that data:

```
services.factory('Summary', ['$q','$rootScope','$http', '$location', function ($q, $rootScope,$http, $location) {

var Service = {};
Service.dataObj = {};
Service.dataObj.d = {"gello":"goodbye"};
....
function listener(data) {
   messageObj = data;
    Service.dataObj.d = data;
  console.log("Received data from websocket: ", messageObj);

}
})]);


controllers.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', 'Summary',
function ($scope, Summary) {

    $scope.click = function(){
        alert(JSON.stringify($scope.summaryinfo));
    }
    $scope.summaryinfo = [Summary.dataObj];
    $scope.summarygridOptions = {
        data: 'summaryinfo'
    };
    console.log("hello");
}]);
```

The data gets pumped in and as far as I was aware because its being stored in Service.dataObj.d if I point my HTML template at Service.dataObj that object is being updated and not replaced so the pointer should remain and the object be watched.

But it doesn't change unless I run the click() method, in which case the UI is affected even though Im just triggering an alert.

What am I missing?

Comment: try use scope.$apply to apply the change.

Comment: spend 4 hours last night trying to figure out what the hell is going on... woke up this morning saw your question and fixed it in 3 mins! Thanks bugg_tb!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably need to use [`$apply()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope):

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries).

```
function listener(data) {
   $scope.$apply(function() {
       Service.dataObj.d = data;
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, knew it would be obvious. I have similar calls in a different project but clearly the initialisation must be different as I don't rely on $apply. As ever something new to learn :)